# Harmonic Mean Calculation and Float Precision

Tags: php, math, floating-point, floating-accuracy, ieee-754

I'm implementing the [Pythagorean means](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_means) in PHP, the arithmetic and geometric means are a piece of cake but I'm having a really hard time coming up with a reliable [**harmonic mean**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_mean) implementation.

This is the [WolframAlpha definition](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=harmonic%20mean):

[image: Harmonic Mean Definition from WolframAlpha]

---

And this is the equivalent implementation in PHP:

```
function harmonicMeanV1()
{
    $result = 0;
    $arguments = func_get_args();

    foreach ($arguments as $argument)
    {
        $result += 1 / $argument;
    }

    return func_num_args() / $result;
}
```

Now, if any of the arguments is `0` this will throw a division by 0 warning, but since `1 / n` is the same as ***n*<sup>-1</sup>** and `pow(0, -1)` gracefully returns the `INF` constant without throwing any errors I could rewrite that to the following (it'll still throw errors if there are no arguments, but lets ignore that for now):

```
function harmonicMeanV2()
{
    $arguments = func_get_args();
    $arguments = array_map('pow', $arguments, array_fill(0, count($arguments), -1));

    return count($arguments) / array_sum($arguments);
}
```

Both implementations work fine for most cases (example [v1](http://codepad.org/pi38gWAL), [v2](http://codepad.org/0kza3RDS) and [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=harmonic%20mean%20%7B40,%2060%7D)), but they fail spectacularly *if the sum of the* **1 / n<sub>*i*</sub>** *series is 0*, I should get another division by 0 warning, but I don't...

Consider the following set: `-2, 3, 6` ([WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=harmonic%20mean%20%7B-2,%203,%206%7D) says it's a complex infinite):

```
  1 / -2    // -0.5
+ 1 / 3     // 0.33333333333333333333333333333333
+ 1 / 6     // 0.16666666666666666666666666666667

= 0
```

However, both my implementations return **`-2.7755575615629E-17` as the sum** ([v1](http://codepad.org/RkcCklUo), [v2](http://codepad.org/ZLdEwU1C)) instead of `0`.

While the return result on CodePad is `-108086391056890000` my dev machine (32-bit) says it's `-1.0808639105689E+17`, still it's nothing like the `0` or `INF` I was expecting. I even tried calling [`is_infinite()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-infinite.php) on the return value, but it came back as `false` as expected.

I also found the [`stats_harmonic_mean()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stats-harmonic-mean.php) function that's part of the `stats` PECL extension, but to my suprise I got the exact same buggy result: `-1.0808639105689E+17`, if any of the arguments is `0`, `0` is returned but no checks are done to the **sum** of the series, [as you can see on **line 3585**](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/pecl/stats/trunk/php_stats.c?revision=313529&view=markup):

```
3557    /* {{{ proto float stats_harmonic_mean(array a)
3558       Returns the harmonic mean of an array of values */
3559    PHP_FUNCTION(stats_harmonic_mean)
3560    {
3561        zval *arr;
3562        double sum = 0.0;
3563        zval **entry;
3564        HashPosition pos;
3565        int elements_num;
3566    
3567        if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "a",  &arr) == FAILURE) {
3568            return;
3569        }
3570        if ((elements_num = zend_hash_num_elements(Z_ARRVAL_P(arr))) == 0) {
3571            php_error_docref(NULL TSRMLS_CC, E_WARNING, "The array has zero elements");
3572            RETURN_FALSE;
3573        }
3574    
3575        zend_hash_internal_pointer_reset_ex(Z_ARRVAL_P(arr), &pos);
3576        while (zend_hash_get_current_data_ex(Z_ARRVAL_P(arr), (void **)&entry, &pos) == SUCCESS) {
3577            convert_to_double_ex(entry);
3578            if (Z_DVAL_PP(entry) == 0) {
3579                RETURN_LONG(0);
3580            }
3581            sum += 1 / Z_DVAL_PP(entry);
3582            zend_hash_move_forward_ex(Z_ARRVAL_P(arr), &pos);   
3583        }
3584    
3585        RETURN_DOUBLE(elements_num / sum);
3586    }
3587    /* }}} */
```

This looks like a typical floating precision bug, but I can't really understand the reason why since the individual calculations are quite precise:

```
Array
(
    [0] => -0.5
    [1] => 0.33333333333333
    [2] => 0.16666666666667
)
```

Is it possible to work around this problem without reverting to the `gmp` / `bcmath` extensions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct. The numbers you are finding are an artifact of the peculiarities of floating-point arithmetic.

Adding more precision will not help you. All you're doing is moving the goal posts.

The bottom line is that the calculations are done *with finite precision*. That means that at some point, an intermediate result will be rounded. That intermediate result is then no longer exact. The error propagates through the calculations, and eventually makes it into your final result. When the exact result is zero, you usually get a numeric result of around 1e-16 with double-precision numbers.

This happens every time your calculation involves a fraction with a denominator that is not a power of 2.

The only way around it is to express the calculations in terms of integers or rational numbers (if you can), and use an arbitrary precision integer package to do the calculations. This is what Wolfram|Alpha does.

Note that the calculation of the geometric mean is not trivial, either. Try a sequence of 20 times 1e20. Since the numbers are all the same, the result should be 1e20. But what you'll find is that the result is infinite. The reason is that the product of those 20 numbers (10e400) is outside the range of double-precision floating-point numbers, and so it's set to infinity. The 20th root of infinity is still infinity.

Finally, a meta-observation: the Pythogarian means really only make sense for positive numbers. What is the geometric mean of 3 and -3? Is it imaginary?? The chain of inequalities on the Wikipedia page you link to are only valid if all values are positive.

Comment: Very nice answer and observations Jeffrey, using a arbitrary precision library does the trick, also rounding to the max precision (`round(array_sum($arguments), ini_get('precision'))`) returns `-0` which might also be a good way to avoid the dependency of `gmp` or `bcmath`. Regarding your meta-observation, you're right. Should I just filter the negative values or use their absolute value?

Comment: @AlixAxel Rounding is moving goal posts. It may work for values that are exactly zero, but will at some point give the wrong result for values very close to 0. Take `H(999999,-999998,-999997,999996)` for example. The result is around `1e+18`, but rounding to max. double precision would give 0.

Comment: @AlixAxel How you handle negative inputs depends on your requirements. If it is purely for informative purposes, then I would just give a warning.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is a problem with floating point precision.  -1/2 can be represented exactly, but 1/3 and 1/6 can't.  Thus when you add them up, you don't quite get zero.

You can do the use-a-common-denominator approach you mentioned (the H2 and H3 formulas you posted), but that just kicks the can down the road a bit, you'll still get inaccurate results once the sum-of-products term starts rounding off.

Why are you taking the harmonic mean of numbers that might be negative, anyway?  That's an inherently unstable calculation (H(-2,3,6+epsilon) varies widely for very small epsilon).

Comment: Thanks Keith, regarding the negative numbers, I was only aiming for completeness but I recon that it doesn't make much sense. Should I filter negative numbers or just use their absolute value?

Comment: @AlixAxel: I would throw an exception, if you can do that in PHP.  If not, return an error code.  Silently ignoring bad input is a bad idea.